# What is the fastest way to data to another Arduino SAMD21 boards

Tags: arduino-zero

Hello I would be needing to transmit data from one arduino to another as fast as possible? how do I achieve this?

Since my application need a lot of pins (its a compact system so mega and due are not suitable) i am going to use 2 arduino nano 33 IOT (basically a SAMD21 uC) and one of them is just going to read from the sensors convert it to binary ( around 32-40 bits long) and send it to the other arduino.

So parameters are:

- must be sent via wires
- maximum number of pines used is 6
- must be able to repeatedly send data ( like this is the only job the arduino does read from sensors and send it to the other one, repeatedly and endlessly)
- must be reliable enough

Thank you Very much !

Comment: SPI is probably the fastest.

Comment: @Majenko Does SPI communication affect/interrupts PWM ?  because  I need to use PWM  on the "master" arduino, and the PWM must not be intterrupted

Comment: No, PWM is (unless the board is crap and uses software PWM) hardware driven and runs in the background.

Comment: what do you mean by "the board is crap"? i mean replica to the arduino boards are using the same chip and schematics as arduino right? they have the schematics on their site

Comment: I mean I am not familiar with the samd21 and how it is used for Arduino.

Comment: can't you use port expanders or multiplexers with one MCU? btw. Nano 33 IoT has two MCU connected by SPI. a SAMD21 and a ESP32

Comment: @juraj It is a custom Nano 33 , so i only have the SAMD21 left, and removed the Nina. Port expanders first time i have hear of those. Do you want to post that as an answer? Because i think it solves my problem and as a bonus making my circuit less complex

Comment: then it is a MKR Zero and not Nano 33 IoT like board

Comment: You are right, but i am following the nano 33's schematics just without the nina. I am not really sure if its the same as the zero. for example i dont have a bms.

Comment: So when looking for port expanders what should i look out for? (exempt for the number of pins)